# Boas práticas no desenvolvimento (Uso de Float, BRs, Api)

Tags: javascript, html, css

gostaria de algumas opiniões de boas práticas no desenvolvimento, pois sou amador no assunto e gostaria que me esclarecessem algumas dúvidas.

1. Quando estou trabalhando no layout utilizo muitas tags BR e Floats para organizar o layout, isso é o mais correto ou existe melhores maneiras?(tinha visto em um site onde o desenvolvedor usava um classe css que definia width:100%, dessa forma ele conseguia fazer pular linha como a tag BR apenas definindo essa classe para as divs)
2. O uso se APIs, comecei a usar uma Apis de previsão do tempo do yahoo, ela disponibiliza algumas formas para receber o retorno, como php e javascript, qual das formas tem melhor desempenho? estou usando php só que fiquei na duvida se quando estiver fazendo consumo da api se o carregamento do site pode ficar prejudicado já que o php executa primeiro e talvez o servidor aguarde a resposta para continuar o processamento da página.

Comment: Dunga,  tente quebrar essa pergunta em 3 para não ficar ampla demais e evitar respostas baseadas em opinião. sua pergunta foi bem formulada, porém é isto que se percebe, pode acontecer de uma pessoa saber responder bem uma ou duas questões e a resposta acaba ficando incompleta

Comment: Consegui reduzi-la para duas perguntas apenas para ficar mais objetivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Sem duvida evite utilizar BR, usar css para isso (padding ou margin)..
É um problema usar  esse tipo de tags/propriedade de css porque caso esteja a fazer o template para mobile e desktop vai encontrar problemas para colocar o conteúdo no sitio correto, isto porque, o espaço dado é relativo ao tamanho do dispositivo que vê o conteúdo.
Em alguns casos faz sentido usar br, caso seja um texto por exemplo.
O meu conselho é usar uma framework para conhecer os conceitos básicos de criação baseada no conteúdo e não no dispositivo. Exemplos: http://getskeleton.com/ ou uma mais completa e a mais conhecida http://getbootstrap.com

2- Eu aconselho duas formas:

- Se quer a máxima performance no tempo de resposta do seu site faça duas ações.. uma em que mostra a pagina normalmente(ação1) e outra que serve ir a api (ação2). Exemplo: Eu visito a página com conteúdo com um tempo de carregamento de 1.5s ao terminar esse carregamento, por AJAX faça um pedido a ação2, que por sua vez faz um pedido a api (por php)
  Este método tem a vantagem de trabalhar só com PHP, tirando a pequena parte de AJAX que faz o pedido, com isto, na minha opinião tem mais controlo sobre tudo.
- A outra forma é ter só uma ação, segundo a lógica em cima, com isto não tem de usar JS para fazer pedidos. Esta forma é útil se a API for muito rápida, normalmente uso esta forma quando a API é minha (está no mesmo servidor) e não perco tempo de resposta

Abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: Esqueci de referir, o google e o utilizador gosta de ver logo algo, por isso é bom sempre baixar o tempo de load de uma pagina, nem que para isso tenha de ir carregando coisas aos poucos ;)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, mais uma ajuda sua...quando eu uso float o objeto acaba saindo do fluxo normal da página, entao quando um desenvolvedor usa float para organizar o layout..ele usa float em todos os elementos?

Comment: Sim, se usar float tem de usar em todos os elementos, porque os que não tiverem float vão estar lá "perdidos".. Raramente tem de usar float, só em casos específicos, como botões no lado direito e esquerdo.. O que controla se um elemento vai para "baixo" ou para o "lado" é a largura da "janela".

Comment: Pois eu uso float demasiadamente para a organização do layout fábio, sempre tive dificuldades em alinhar horizontalmente divs, porem estou fazendo uso de display:inline e colocando os elementos dentro de uma div container com width;100%, me sinto menos amador com essa prática do que usando float em tudo.

Comment: Sim.. com o tempo vai encontrando maneiras melhores para chegar ao resultado :)
Qualquer duvida disponha...

Answer (score 1):

1)A tag BR pula uma linha, não há problema em usar tag 
 porem o seu layout não pode ser baseado em linhas puladas ou não. Procure utilizar CSS pra isso, de preferencia crie classes css e aplique-as aos elementos ao invez de usar o atributo style em cada elemento da pagina, isso vai deixar o codigo mais facil de manter e mais legivel, sem falar na economia de escrita e tamanho final. Estude margin e padding (CSS), eles são os corretos quando vc quer distanciar uma coisa da outra.

2)Pode utilizar float sem problemas, é com ele mesmo que vc direciona a orientação do elemento. Mas procure sempre usar float em uma DIV. Procure sempre manter seu codigo encapsulado em divs, dessa forma vc pode controlar melhor o conteudo e ter uma melhor organização.

3) O consumo dessa API é quase que irrelevante, porque é um processamento fora da sua pagina, vc apenas recebe o resultado. Agora se a API demora pra responder nao tem muito o que fazer. Javascript sempre vai ser mais rapido do que qualquer coisa quando o assunto é web, já que é uma linguagem de scripts já entendida pelo browser. PHP tem suas vantagens assim como o javascript.

4) Procure separar sim as coisas, css no head e script no final da pagina dentro do body da pagina. Desta forma a pagina é exibida antes de se carregar os scritps.

Eu fortemente indico você aprender HTML, CSS e Javascript primeiro, seja bom nesses 3. Quando você souber javascript de verdade, você terá um futuro muito fácil com desenvolvimento web.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, já desenvolvo há algum tempo, porem sou meio autodidata e apesar de ter um conhecimento razoável nas linguagens eu percebo que nos meu layouts parece que tem muita gambiarra, margins absurdas, entao busco sempre achar boas praticas, pois além de facilitar o desenvolvimento ajuda na manutenção.

Comment: @DungaCardoso conhece bootstrap? Ele pode te dar uma ajuda monstra com layout. Hoje em dia ninguem mais fica reinventando a roda com layout. É importante saber como fazer, saber o que cada coisa no css faz e etc. Mas é muito mais produtivo usar bootstrap ou outro framework css.  http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Rocha, apenas ouvi falar, eu sou daqueles que preferem a forma bruta do que usar frameworks por questão mais de aprendizado, como o site que estou desenvolvendo é bem simples acaba que estou evitando usar framework pra fazer poucas funções, mesmo assim vou procurar mais me informar sobre o bootstrap..

Comment: @DungaCardoso boa! Mas não rejeite-os, bootstrap é praticamente essencial em qualquer projeto real que você for pegar, é item obrigatorio pra web devs :D Bons estudos, vc ja ta na direção certa!

Comment: Rocha...dei uma pequena pesquisa...achei muito interessante...porem só pretendo usar framework em projetos maiores e bem mais complexos. Obrigado